Flutter Check Variable for Updates
I am working on a widget that holds a list view of future appointments. But the information I need is fetched with an async function. This function loads a couple of items a second but takes a while to finish. To speed up the time, I fetched the info the moment the app started.
Main Method
Future main() async {
  void initAppointmentList() async {
    await AppointmentList().init(30);
  }
  initAppointmentList();
}

Appointment List Fetching
class AppointmentList {
  List<Map<String, String>> appointments = [];

  Future init(int range) async {
    for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
      /*
        HTTP GET Code fetching data
      */
      appointments.add(/* The Data */);
      }
      day = day.add(const Duration(days:1));
    }
    
  }
}

Flutter Widgets
class AppointmentOverviewContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppointmentOverviewContainer({super.key});

  @override
  State<AppointmentOverviewContainer> createState() => _AppointmentOverviewContainerState();
}

class _AppointmentOverviewContainerState extends State<AppointmentOverviewContainer> {
  List<Map<String, String>> appointments = AppointmentList().appointments;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (/* If Appointment List Has At Least One Item Loaded */) ?
      FittedBox (
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: Text(appointments[0]['Name'] ?? '',
          style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
      ) : 
      FittedBox (
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: Text('Loading Appointments',
          style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Is there a way that the Flutter widget can check if the appointment list has been updated? If it has, display the most recent one. However, I also want it so it is able to check when the fetching has completely finished.

Since the async function was initialized in the main method, I can't use the FutureBuilder

I can't use setState because the variable updating is done externally to the widget

Putting the fetching inside of the widget prevents me from running it in the beginning



You could look at things like dart Streams or a library like BloC

Fetch the info in a stateful widget at the top of your tree.  there's not any measurabl e difference between that and somewhere in main().

You can make AppointmentList extend ChangeNotifier and subscribe to it in the widget. Then you can trigger a setState each time an appointment is fetch.
class AppointmentList extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Map<String, String>> appointments = [];

  Future init(int range) async {
    for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
      /*
        HTTP GET Code fetching data
      */
      appointments.add(/* The Data */);
      notifyListeners();
      }
      day = day.add(const Duration(days:1));
    }
  }
}

And in the widget state
class _AppointmentOverviewContainerState extends State<AppointmentOverviewContainer> {
  final appointmentList = AppointmentList();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    appointmentList.addListener(_onAppointmentAdded);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (/* If Appointment List Has At Least One Item Loaded */) ?
      FittedBox (
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: Text(appointmentList.appointments.first['Name'] ?? '',
          style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
      ) : 
      FittedBox (
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: Text('Loading Appointments',
          style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
      appointmentList.removeListener(_onAppointmentAdded);
  }

  void _onAppointmentAdded(){
    setState((){
      //Do your logic
    });
  }

But for this to work, you should initialize the appointment list in the Widget because you won't have the same instance in main and in your widget. Unless you have some dependencies injection.
I agree with Randal Schwartz's comment. You won't get visible performance by fetching data from main instead of in initState from your widget.

"You won't get visible performance by fetching data from main instead of in initState from your widget."
The widget is located on a separate page, so it only reaches initState when the user chooses to go to that page. Would initializing it in the main method allow it to have more information to display than initializing in the widget's initState? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you for your help.
